# Horizontal 100% menu but vertical submenu items

Tags: html, css, menu

I've made an horizontal menu that all menu items take 100% of the nav. To do this, I use display:table in 'lu', and display:table-cell in 'li'. In this way the menu is horizontal and extends all manu items to 100% width. The problem is the submenu is also horizontally but I want the submenu items vertically.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').ready(function() {
           $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
              $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
           });
        });
    </script>

    ul#navigation {
        float:left;
        display:table;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
        font-size:15px;
        background-color:#FFF;
    }

    ul#navigation li {
        display: table-cell;
        margin:0;
        padding:14px 3px 14px 3px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    ul.sub_navigation {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color:#FFF;
        opacity:0.8;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    ul.sub_navigation li {
        clear:both;
    }

    ul#navigation li a,
    ul#navigation li a:active,
    ul#navigation li a:visited {
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
    }
    ul#navigation li a:hover {
        color:#478961;
    }



    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub_navigation">
               <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="">Sub item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

What can I add to sub_navigation styles to show subenu items vertically?

Thanks
Victor

Comment: make a jsfiddle with some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the elements are set to `clear:both`, simply add `float:left` to the li elements in the subnavigation.

```
ul.sub_navigation li {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing so without floats if that's what you want:

```
    ul.sub_navigation li a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/